# $f(z)$ and $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ simultaneously holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that the functions $f(z)$ and $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ are simultaneously holomorphic.

I take this to mean that $f(z)$ is holomorphic if and only if $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic.

Let $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$. Note that $\overline{g(\overline{z})}=f(z)$. So it suffices to prove that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic, then $g(z)$ is holomorphic.

Write $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$. Since $f(z)$ is holomorphic, the real and imaginary parts satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$$\frac{\partial{u(z)}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{v(z)}}{\partial{y}}, \frac{\partial{u(z)}}{\partial{y}} = -\frac{\partial{v(z)}}{\partial{x}}.$$

We have $g(z) = u(\overline{z})+i(-v(\overline{z}))$. To prove that $g(z)$ is holomorphic, we must prove that its real and imaginary parts satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$$\frac{\partial{u(\overline{z})}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{(-v(\overline{z}))}}{\partial{y}}, \frac{\partial{u(\overline{z})}}{\partial{y}} = -\frac{\partial{(-v(\overline{z}))}}{\partial{x}}.$$

How can we obtain this from the above relations?

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: See my response at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470597/criterions-for-holomorphic-functions/470612#470612.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Usually the chain rule in one variable is $\dfrac{df(g(x))}{dx} = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. What would be the form here? I'm thinking of $\dfrac{\partial v(x,-y)}{\partial y} = (\dfrac{\partial v(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)})(\dfrac{d(-y)}{dy}) = -\dfrac{\partial v(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)}$. Is that written correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know that I am not answering your final question, but anyway... if $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline z)}$, then

$$\begin{align*}
g^\prime(a)=&\,\lim_{z\to a}\frac{g(z)-g(a)}{z-a}\\[2mm]
=&\,\lim_{z\to a}\frac{\overline{f(\overline z)}-\overline{f(\overline a)}}{z-a}\\[2mm]
=&\,\lim_{z\to a}\frac{\overline{f(\overline z)-f(\overline a)}}{\overline{\ \overline{z-a}\ }}\\[2mm]
=&\,\lim_{z\to a}\overline{\,\Biggl[\frac{f(\overline z)-f(\overline a)}{\overline z-\overline a}\Biggr]}\\[2mm]
=&\,\overline{\lim_{z\to a}\,\frac{f(\overline z)-f(\overline a)}{\overline z-\overline a}}\\[2mm]
=&\,\overline{\lim_{w\to\overline a}\,\frac{f(w)-f(\overline a)}{w-\overline a}}\\[2mm]
=&\overline{f^\prime(\overline a)}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, $g$ is holomorphic. The converse is proved similarly (or you can use the fact that the transformation $f\mapsto g$ is idempotent, that is, you return to your original function $f$ when applied twice).

Comment: I think this is a better approach than using the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  It is better to just stay with the complex arguments when you can, instead of going to x + iy.  The reason is that the x + iy computations tend to be more complicated, so it is easier to make arithmetic mistakes.  Of course, sometimes this is the only way to do the problem; but it's always worth looking for a simpler alternative.

Comment: @matematicos, you have used $z\rightarrow a$ then $w=\overline z\rightarrow a$ won't it converge to $\overline a$

Comment: @Human You are right. Correcting now.

Answer (score 5):

Proof based in holomorphic $\implies$ locally power series:
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-c)^n,$$
$$
\tilde f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})} =
\overline{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (\overline{z}-c)^n} =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\overline{a_n (\overline{z}-c)^n} =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\overline{a}_n(z-\overline{c})^n,
$$
where the third equality is true because the continuity of conjugation.

Comment: This is a really cool proof, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) is an extremely useful tool when one wants to prove a function is holomophic but doesn't want to look at derivatives explicitly. In this case, let $\gamma$ be a simple closed curve.

$\int _\gamma \overline{f(\overline{z})} dz = \overline{\int _\gamma f(\overline{z}) dz} = \int _\gamma f(\overline{z}) d\overline{z} = -\int_{\overline{\gamma}} f(u) du$
where $\overline{\gamma}$ is the curve $\gamma$, reflected with respect to the x-axis and the - comes from the corresponding change of the orientation from counterclockwise to clockwise.

Now, by the above inequality and Morera's theorem:
$f(z)$ is holomorphic iff its integral over an arbitrary simple closed curve is $0$ iff $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic, which we wanted to prove.