# $f(z)$ and $g\circ f(z)$ holomorphic implies $g(z)$ holomorphic as well

Tags: complex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a connected open set and let $f,g$ be non-constant functions defined on $\Omega$ and $f(\Omega)$ respectively.

Suppose that both $f$ and $g\circ f\in H(\Omega)$. Prove that $g\in H(f(\Omega))$.

---

I've made progress on this problem from two directions; one using the limit definition of holomorphicity, and the other via the open mapping theorem. However, I don't have enough faith in the rigor of my techniques and am looking for an airtight approach or suggestion from others.

---

Inspired by problem $10.14$ in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*

Answer (score 4):

If $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ for some $z_0$ then $f$ is invertible in a neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$, its inverse is holomorphic, so $g=(g\circ f)\circ f^{-1}$ is holomorphic on $f(U)$. If $f'(z_0)=0$ then $f'(z)\neq0$ in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ (except for $z_0$ itself) - so $g$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$, except possibly at $z_0$. As a result, $g$ is holomorphic on $f(\Omega)$ minus a discrete subset. From here it's easy to see that $g$ is continuous, so just apply Riemann's removable singularity theorem to see that $g$ is holomorphic$.

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection I am wary about the start of your last sentence (where you go from $g$ holomorphic on $f(\Omega)\setminus Z(f')$ to $g$ being continuous.) This implication relies on $g\circ f$ being holomorphic (otherwise, it is not true; set $g(z)=1_{z=0}$ for a counterexample.) I am starting to think you will need to replicate some of the argument I outlined in my proof sketch to complete this step. Can you elaborate this point?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with a proof today; here's a sketch:

After applying the Open Mapping Theorem and some manipulations, we can reduce the original statement to showing $$g(z^n)\in H(\{0\})\implies g(z)\in H(\{0\})$$
Now expand the power series for $g(z^n)$ at $0$ and substitute $z\to \lambda z$ where $\lambda^n=1$. By comparing coefficients, we can construct a power series by hand that converges to $g(z)$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the complex variant of the chain rule. See, for example, my response to [criterions for holomorphic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470597/criterions-for-holomorphic-functions/470612#470612).

Edit: I was assuming $g$ was real differentiable. I sit corrected. :) Still a useful technique to have in one's bag of tricks.

Comment: Could you flesh out this idea a little more? I see what you are suggesting (it is similar to my "limit definition" approach, which I apologize for not fleshing out further). However, I would be interested to see how you avoid some of the subtleties I ran into that prevented a rigorous proof.

Comment: @TedShifrin: To use the chain rule you need to know that $g$ is differentiable, but the question does not assume even continuity. On the other hand, user8268 gave an answer which avoids these issues.