# composition with biholomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $f:G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ be a local biholomorphism and $g:G_2 \rightarrow G_1 $ continious
such that $(f\circ g)(z)=z$

Proof that $g$ is a biholomorphism

I know that $g$ is biholomorphic if $g' \gt 0$ for all $z\in G_2$ and $g^{-1}$ is continious.

How do I know that $g$ is already a holomorphic function ?
 
Can someone give me a hint/ or explain why $g$ is holomorphic if $g$ is continous and satisfies the condition above ?

Comment: This looks like a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485384/fz-and-g-circ-fz-holomorphic-implies-gz-holomorphic-as-well.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283713/let-fu-to-v-be-a-bijective-holomorphic-function-show-that-inverse-of-f-is?

Comment: @MartinR In my case it´s a local biholomorphism.