# Help on a problem from Ahlfors' Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

This is a problem on Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*.

**If $g(w)$ and $f(z)$ are analytic functions, show that $g(f(z))$ is also analytic.**

I've tried this and I have stumbled upon a tricky partial differential equation.
I can't seem to use the Cauchy-Riemann condition of $g, f$ and use it to get the result.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you edit what you got and how you got it into your question, and explain why you're stuck at that point. Maybe someone here will know what to do with the PDE you've found.

Comment: At this point you shouldn't be confusing holomorphic (complex differentiable on $U$), analytic (represented by power series around every points) and entire (represented by a single power series). Can you show the composition of two entire functions is an entire function ?

Comment: @reuns: Mathematicians and complex analysis textbooks do not often make your distinction (although *I* personally did when I taught the material). In particular, Ahlfors does not.

Comment: I am new to the subject, and I'm self studying, just finished Rudin principles of mathematical analysis

Comment: I will post what I got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my copy of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* the real cain rule is Theorem $5.5$ on page 90. Exactly the same proof can be used to show that when $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ and $g$ is complex differentiable at $w_0=f(z_0)$ then $h:=g\circ f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$. By *complex differentiable* I mean that
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}{f(z)-f(z_0)\over z-z_0}\in{\mathbb C}$$
exists.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this and this seems more simpler than using Cauchy reimann condition,

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use the chain rule phrased in terms of $\partial/\partial z$ and $\partial/\partial\bar z$. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470597/criterions-for-holomorphic-functions/470612#470612). Conveniently, Ahlfors defines those on the page before your question appears.